# Corountine: non-blocking code in `GlobalScope.launch{..}` doesn't work as expected on Kotlin Playgrond site

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have some lines of code.
**Case 1:**

```
 GlobalScope.launch {
       delay(1000L)
       println("world")
 }
 println("hello")
 runBlocking {
      delay(2000L)
 }
 // or I can use
 Thread.sleep(2000L)
```

The result will be:

```
hello
world
```

**Case 2:**
If I remove the `runBlocking{...}` block or `Thread.sleep(2000L)`, or change delay time < 700L, the result just only:

```
hello
```

**Case 3:**
If I change the delay time 800L <= time <.100L then the result is:

```
world hello  // without newline character after "world" but include a space character.
```

What a strange!
I don't understand why it leads to this result. In case 2, the coroutine doesn't execute if `runBlocking{...}` block or `Thread.sleep(2000L)` are omitted? Blocking code `runBlocking{..}` block or `Thread.sleep(2000L)` are required in order the non-blocking code `GlobalScope.launch{...}` can be executed? I'm using https://play.kotlinlang.org/ tool to run the code.

Comment: As soon as you let `main()` complete, your program is over. It doesn't wait for the completion of the launched coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

Check code bellow:

```
fun main() {
runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { // launch a new coroutine and continue
        delay(1000L) // non-blocking delay for 1 second (default time unit is ms)
        println("World!") // print after delay
    }
    println("Hello") // main coroutine continues while a previous one is delayed

    launch {
        delay(2000L)
        println("Kotlin")
    }
}
```

}

Result will be:

```
Hello
World!
Kotlin
```